# How can I run multiple tests for one controller load or Capypara page load in RSpec?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec, capybara

I would like to test multiple aspects of a controller or page's behavior as separate tests, but speed up my tests but only running a controller or capybara page load once for multiple checks. As an example, with a controller test:

```
      it "should include all videos in the list of all videos" do
        get :show, id: event.id
        response.should be_somehow
      end

      it "should set the main video to be the paid video" do
        get :show, id: event.id
        response.should be_somehow_else
      end
```

I'd like this to become:

```
      before :all do
        get :show, id: event.id
      end

      it "should include all videos in the list of all videos" do
        response.should be_somehow
      end

      it "should set the main video to be the paid video" do
        response.should be_somehow_else
      end
```

The problem is that RSpec cleans out the response object (or, for capybara, the page object) after every test. So whether I'm checking `assigns` in controller tests, `response` objects, or `page` results in Capybara, nothing like this works:

```
before :all do
  get :show, id: event.id
  @response = response
end
example "it should do something" do
  @response.should be_somehow # test works
end
example "it should do something else" do
  @response.should be_somehow_else # test fails; @response has been flushed by Rails testing facilities
end
```

So the solution for test speedup is to have multiple checks in a single test:

```
example "it should be totally correct in every way" do
  get :show, id: event.id
  response.should be_somehow # test works
  response.should be_somehow_else # test works
end
```

But this grates my sensibilities on test naming.

This is by far the most aggravating in Capybara, in which I might have a multi-step setup (login, permissioning) process, and have 15 things to check on a single page load: did all the correct things show? Did other, uncorrect things not show? Did javascript actions get bound to the right things? Did the right backbone template get rendered? These tests quickly become 20 continuous lines of `should` statements with Ruby comments inline so I can remember what I'm testing, and it's just a mess.

Before everyone tells me not to maintain test state from test to test, that's not what I'm doing: I want to check independent variables associated with a single state.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

This seems like an excellent time for VCR to enter the picture. For instance:

```
before :all do
  event = Event.create
  VCR.use_cassette('show_event') do
    make_http_request(:get, "http://localhost:3000/event/#{event.id}")
    make_http_request(:get, "http://localhost:3000/#{event.id}")
  end
end

it "should include all videos in the list of all videos" do
  use_vcr_cassette "show_event"
  response.should be_somehow
end

it "should set the main video to be the paid video" do
  use_vcr_cassette "show_event"
  response.should be_somehow_else
end
```

This'll make a request before all (not each) of the tests are run, store it in YAML, and then pick at the YAML for each test.

This reduces your overhead, changing to IO bound instead of Rack/Environment bound.

Comment: Wouldn't this record the output of my site once, and then never change?

Comment: VCR can record a number of ways, actually. Yes, it can if you want, or you can do it each time. Or once every blue moon!

Comment: This does not seem to be the case for localhost, though. VCR will either not work at all on localhost, or completely turn itself off. I don't think this will work :/

Comment: And it doesn't help with controller tests, which would also be awesome .